# When to pick 'Natural' over 'Integer' in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, integer, primitive-types, integer-arithmetic

Not long ago I've discovered [`Natural`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Numeric-Natural.html) data type in `base`. It's supposed to be taken (as it seems to me) when you intend to use non-negative integer type. But it's not exactly clear why should I prefer `Natural` to `Integer`. Both types have arbitrary precision, both have quite optimized runtime representation — [`Integer` representation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1/docs/src/GHC.Integer.Type.html#Integer) and [`Natural` representation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Natural.html#Natural). But `Natural` [can throw pure exceptions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Natural.html#minusNatural) when you subtract natural numbers and this doesn't really add more typesafety to your code. While `Integer` is more popular across all packages.

So when and why should I use `Natural`?

Comment: This could be a bit opinionated, but my criterion would be "if you'd prefer a runtime error to a negative result, choose `Natural`"

Comment: @chi Agree. While we have `negate` and `(-)` inside `Num` type class not much we can do to not allow subtractions.

Answer (score 7):

I do not see why you want to use `Natural` or `Integer`. Why not use `Rational` instead? It is arbitrary precision, has an optimised runtime representation, and works for naturals, integers, *and* rationals!

My point is that we should choose a type which makes sense semantically. Lets count the houses on the street with naturals, record our next golf game with integers, and divide a fresh blueberry pie with rationals.

Comment: I don't know what parts (if any) of this are meant sarcastically. I think you should better write clearly what your opinion is.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I encourage you to add a second answer in a different rhetorical style.

Comment: @erisco The reason to pick `Natural` because of semantic sense is a good reason. But then: why not `newtype Natural = Natural Integer`? `Rational` is much-much slower than `Integer` or `Natural` because of constant calls to `gcd` function. But it's not clear which one — `Natural` or `Integer` — is slower because of compiler optimizations and inlining and all that stuff. My question is not just «duh, I have two types, emm... what should I use? I'm so stupid, I can't choose». But why create such `Natural` type with such semantic. Why exception instead saturation? What benefits I can gain?

Comment: @erisco I don't have a clear opinion on this yet that I could could write. Haskell traditionally does not distinguish positive and general integers through the type system and has fared pretty well with it. I furthermore tend to use only integers that could actually adress/index something in memory, and fast, hence my go-to type is actually `Int`. But that's not to say I don't see why it might make sense to opt for `Integer` or indeed `Natural` in some applications, I just don't know when this is worth it.

Comment: @Shersh you offered good reasons based on the implementation of `Integer` and `Natural` to be unconvinced that `Natural` has a use. I have no reason or interest to argue with that. You broadly asked "when and why" to use Natural, however, and so I gave the reason I think is important. This reason has nothing to do with implementation. I have no reason against `newtype Natural = Natural Integer`. The benefit to me is semantics, not the implementation.

Comment: @erisco Why does Haskell itself then not stick to semantically sensible choices? E.g. `:t length` shows that its result type is `Int` and not `Natural`. That can be annoying if you yourself want to stick to semantically sensible choices. What is the motivation behind the typing of `length`?

Comment: @TomVerhoeff The motivation for using `Int` is that 32-bit signed integer operations are much faster on most CPUs. You can use `genericLength` otherwise.